# Split on caps and numbers

Tags: regex, perl

How can I split a variable on upper case letters and number my variable looks like this

```
$Var = "HvacSystem8000Series";
```

Needed result is:

```
$Var = "Hvac System 8000 Series";
```

Code:

```
$Var =~ s/^[A-Z]/ /igs;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explanation in the comments:

```
$Var = "HvacSystem8000Series";
$Var =~ s/(?<=[[:lower:]])   # Low case before,
          (?=[[:upper:]0-9]) # upper case or digit after;
          |                  # OR
          (?<=[0-9])         # digit before,
          (?=[[:upper:]])    # upper case after?
          /\ /xg;            # Replace with a space.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simplest to collect a list of what you consider to be *words* and join them back together with a space separator.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = "HvacSystem8000Series";
$var = join ' ', $var =~ /[A-Z]+[a-z]*|\d+/g;

print $var
```

**output**

```
Hvac System 8000 Series
```